# MongoDB amount of entries

Tags: mongodb, querying

How get amount of entries (in collection), that hold only unique data in certain key?

For example:

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("4f9d996eba6a7aa62b0005ed"),
   "tag": "web" 
}
{
   "_id": ObjectId("4f9d996eba6a7aa62b0006ed"),
   "tag": "net" 
}
{
   "_id": ObjectId("4f9d996eba6a7aa62b0007ed"),
   "tag": "web" 
}
{
   "_id": ObjectId("4f9d996eba6a7aa62b0008ed"),
   "tag": "page" 
}
```

Amount of entries with unique key "tag", and return 3.

ps: If it possible, how get list of all found unique values of key: "tag"?

Answer (score 2):

To get a `unique` list of values you need to either `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY`. MongoDB supports both paradigms:

- [Distinct](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation#Aggregation-Distinct)
- [Group](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation#Aggregation-Group)

To get a list of all distinct `tag` values you would run:

```
db.mycollection.distinct('tag');
```

or

```
db.runCommand({ distinct: 'mycollection', key: 'tag' })
```

and you can get the count by just looking at the `length` of the result:

```
db.mycollection.distinct('tag').length
```

Note on `distinct` command from the documentation: `Note: the distinct command results are returned as a single BSON object.  If the results could be large (> max document size – 4/16MB ), use map/reduce instead`

Comment: Thank you! I have only 14 points, but Your answer deserves +1.

Comment: FYI: This solution will work, but only in versions 2.2+. 2.2 hasn't been released yet as of 2012-05-15. To use it at the moment, you'll have to grab a 2.1 development build.

Comment: @SeanReilly `db.version()` returns 2.0.5 on my local instance and I checked the code before submitting it. it worked. what part of if shouldn't have worked?

Comment: Good point. Distinct works now. The larger aggregation framework functionality is what's coming in 2.2+. My apologies.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Map/Reduct](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce) to group entries.

I create content with the name of "content" and inserted 4 data (that you listed above) in it. Then by using the following map/reduce code you can group them by their tag. At the end result is written into the content name "result".

```
var map = function() {
    emit(this.tag, 1);
};

var reduce = function(key,values){
    var result = 0;
    for(v in values){
        result += values[v];
    }
    return result;
};

res = db.content.mapReduce(map,reduce,{out:"result"}});
```

Result is shown as follows.

```
{ "_id" : "net", "value" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "page", "value" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "web", "value" : 2 }
```

Comment: Thank you! I have only 14 points, but Your answer deserves +1.